# Notify new user of account - must provide at least one recipient email address... doesn't send email

Tags: 6, users, emails

I've searched for a long time, but I can't find anything that helps.

Basically, when a user is created, I input a username, password, and email address.  Then, when I check the "notify user of new account" box and save the user, I go to a white screen with plain text saying: "Invalid address: You must provide at least one recipient email address." I checked the logs and the email doesn't have a "to" address.

Also, when I do login (or masquerade) with the new user, the site has a prompt stating that I need to provide a valid email because there isn't one for that user, despite a valid email address having been input at the time of creation.  When I enter the email address in this prompt, then it is saved to that user (meaning I go to the edit tab of a user and see the email address there).

Everything I've come across says it could be one module or the other... but I don't have any of those modules referenced.

I have SMTP authentication support.
I have Simple Mail.

I am able to send out test emails and other mails (i.e. from a triggered action), but not to notify users of a new account.

I'm sorry if this has been covered elsewhere... I've looked but haven't found anything that works.

Also- I'm working with Drupal 6.

It's similar to this issue: [to email address not populated](http://drupal.org/node/835754)

Thanks.

Comment: is it drupal 7 or 6 and if u use drupal 7 did you check the email of the site in configuration -> site information

Comment: Drupal 6... Sorry I should've mentioned that.  Yes I checked that and I have an email in there.  All of my other modules are up to date.  I'm wondering if SMTP and PHPMailer are clashing? But why would that prevent a user's email from being saved?

Comment: Yes I checked and there is no email address showing up in the user profile.